# CKeditor - Images not showing in website frontend

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

While using ckeditor to add an image, the image is displayed and it works fine.

But when this code is saved in my database and then later reload the website frontend, the images don't show up anymore, although if you look at the source the 'img' tags are still there.

Tested in FF, Chrome, Safari and IE. No images.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: show code to us

Comment: After debugging, the error code is related to blob contents. The website can't load blob contents stored in my DB when refreshing